# Dimensiones Jframe y paint

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy intentando hacer una ventana que se divida en cuadriculas de una forma proporcional a sus dimensiones, es decir a mayor dimensión mas cuadrados hay en la cuadricula, a menor dimensión menos cuadrados habrá. el caso que quiero crear un cuadrado general, pero el problema viene que cuando lo pinto las dimensiones del cuadrado quedan por debajo de la ventada como si estuviese descuadrado.

```
    public Frame(){

    window = new JFrame();


    window.setContentPane(this);
    window.addComponentListener(this);

    window.setBounds(100,100,600,600);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.addMouseListener(this);

    System.out.println(window.getSize());
    //comments

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {


    super.paint(g);
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    contador = 0;
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(1, 1, 599, 599);






}
```

Creo que es por el tema de que el JFrame mide lo que es toda la ventana y los dibujos van en el JPanel, pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo que se ajuste o coger la dimensión de ese JPanel para así poder ajustar el primer cuadro.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, java toma en cuenta la barra de titulo y los bordes como tamaño, para comprobar eso puedes quitar los bordes con una simple sentencia:

```
tuVentana.setUndecorated(true);
```

y notaras que dibuja como debería, para conocer los el tamaño de los bordes que tienes en tu JFrame utiliza lo siguiente:

```
    TuFrame ventana = new TuFrame();

    Insets bordes = ventana.getInsets();

    System.out.println(bordes.top);//Arriba
    System.out.println(bordes.left);//Izquierdo
    System.out.println(bordes.right);//Derecho
    System.out.println(bordes.bottom);//Abajo
```

Esto imprimirá el tamaño de los bordes de tu ventana en mi caso fueron:

> Arriba: 31
>
> Izquierda, derecha y abajo: 8

No estoy seguro si afecta dependiendo el sistema operativo.

NOTA: Esto **NO** funciona si utilizas:

```
Insets bordes = this.getInsets();//Dentro de tu clase del frame.
```

Saludos